# Pre-select selected options in bootstrap multi select with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have implemented [bootstrap multi-select](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect) in my application for multi-select. I am having an issue with Pre-selecting values in edit form. Below is the js code I have used:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tincludeds').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            selectAllJustVisible: false,
            enableFiltering: true,
            numberDisplayed: 1,
            maxHeight: 600,
            buttonWidth: '400px',
            select: {!! json_encode($tour->tIncludeds()->allRelatedIds()) !!}
        });
    });
</script>
```

But the script is not working. Is there anything that I have missed in here ? Below is the output of `{{ dd(json_encode($tour->tIncludeds()->allRelatedIds())) }}`

Html code of multi-select field in of my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tincluded">Includeds</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tincludeds" multiple="multiple" name="tincludeds[]" class="tincluded">
        @foreach($tincludeds as $included)
        <option value="{{ $included->id }}">{{ $included->name }}</option>t
        @endforeach   
    </select>   
    @if ($errors->has('tincludeds'))
    <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('tincludeds')}}</span>                            
    @endif  
</div>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: there must be some error in your json

Comment: `json_encode($tour->tExcludeds()->allRelatedIds())` is correct I've checked it with dump and die `dd()` method.

Comment: Will you please show the HTML/Laravel code for your multi-select dropdown ?

Comment: Can you please attach the output of the allRelatedIds function?

Comment: maybe i'm missing something but I haven't seen a "select" parameter for the multiselect plugin in their manual.

Comment: Documentation of bootstrap multi-select has stated to use this method `.multiselect('select', value, triggerOnChange)`. But how do I implement this ??

Comment: @Pratik I've added the HTML code above

Comment: as @OfirBaruch said, there is no any select option present. you need to do custom coding for this. Something like this:
<option value="{{ $included->id }}"   <?php echo in_array($included->id, $listofIds) ? 'selected' : ''?> >{{ $included->name }}</option>

Comment: @Pratik can you please put down your suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your code:

```
<?php     
    $listofIds = $tour->tIncludeds()->allRelatedIds(); // array with list of ids
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tincluded">Includeds</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tincludeds" multiple="multiple" name="tincludeds[]" class="tincluded">
        @foreach($tincludeds as $included)
           <option value="{{ $included->id }}" <?php echo in_array($included->id, $listofIds) ? 'selected' : ''?> >{{ $included->name }}</option>
        @endforeach   
    </select>   
    @if ($errors->has('tincludeds'))
    <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('tincludeds')}}</span>                            
    @endif  
</div>
```

If `$listofIds` is coming from a controller as an object, you need to change it to an  array either in view or in controller
In controller:

```
$listofIds = Model::pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Or in View `$listofIds->toArray()` before passing to the `in_array()` function

Comment: with your snippet I'getting error message `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given `

Comment: @TanjaForsberg $listofIds  should be an array. you can simply print & check whether it is or not